# How do I save the amount of cash a player has when they leave and rejoin my roblox game?

Tags: roblox

I need to have a cash system where when a player leaves the game, and joins on another day, the amount of "Cash" they have saves. Could I have some help. Thanks.

Comment: If you need a place to start, have you checked out the tutorial for it? https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Saving-Player-Data

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it locally on Roblox. You will need to have a database online that will save the state of cash to that player when he leaves, and also get it when the same player joins. Authentication is very important here

Comment: How do u do that?

Comment: Roblox supports data storage out of the box. Their DataStoreService is specifically designed for this.

Comment: You could use third-party modules that work with DataStores such as DataStore2, ProfileService, etc.